# Access denied when user try to use Alert Me on a list - WSS v3

Tags: permissions, alert

I have some users who have contribute access on a list and read access on the site but anytime a user tries to alert himself he gets

> Error: Access Denied

Why is this?
I even gave the user Full Control on the list, still the same issue!

Comment: Please mark an Answer if you found one useful. ;)

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem recently. In my case, a user had `Contribute` access to a list but at the site level had `Restricted Read`. `Restricted Read` doesn't have the `Create Alerts` permission. Replacing the site permissions with `Read` resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

To expand a little on @David Clarke's sound answer, let's discuss the following three scenarios and their minimum required permissions within the Role / Permission Levels:

1. **Add Own Alert**

   *Requires*: `Create Alerts`
2. **Manage Own Alerts**

   *Requires*: `Open Items`
3. **Add / Manage Alerts of Other Users**

   *Requires*: `Manage Alerts` - at site level

Scenarios 1 & 2 may also require `View Application Pages` if not already granted via another role. Without this permission at or above the scope (site, list, item) where you want to create the Alert, you will not have the option. Furthermore, you may also be redirected to the notoriously obnoxious "Access Denied" page.

Confirmed (i.e. the same permissions exist) in SharePoint 2007 through SharePoint Online.

Answer (score 0):

The permission to create alerts is actually at the site level.  By default, I don't think the OOTB Visitors/Readers group can do this.

Answer (score 0):

Do the site permissions allow for persnalization permissions?  In the Shared Service Provider of Central Administration, do all authenticated users have personalization permissions defined in Personalization services permissions, assuming your on 2007?

Comment: PirateEric this is a WSS v3 - 2007 .I don't think i have a shared service provider in the Central Admin.

Answer (score 0):

It is a known issue, you should give the users permissions on the paren web as well, as discussed [here](https://pholpar.wordpress.com/2015/01/29/the-pitfall-of-sharepoint-alerts/):

> You can create the alert from the list ribbon via the application page
>   `SubNew.aspx`, and manage them via the `MySubs.aspx` page, both of them
>   are located in the `_layouts` folder. The code behind class for these
>   pages are the `SubNewPage` and the `MySubsPage` classes respectively from
>   the assembly `Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages` (and the same
>   namespace). There is no security check in the `OnLoad` method of the
>   `SubNewPage` class (nor in its base classes), however in the `OnLoad`
>   method of the `MySubsPage` class the `CheckRights` method of the
>   `LayoutsPageBase` class (`Microsoft.SharePoint` assembly,
>   `Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls` namespace ) is called. This method
>   checks, if the current user has `DefaultLayoutsRights` permission (that
>   means `SPBasePermissions.EmptyMask | SPBasePermissions.ViewFormPages | SPBasePermissions.Open | SPBasePermissions.ViewPages`) on the parent
>   web, and not on the list. If not, the user is not able to manage the
>   alerts she created earlier.